# What does the Term Ragdoll mean?

Tags: game-engine, add-on

I wonder what the term Ragdoll in [BRIK - Blender Ragdoll Implementation Kit](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Game_Engine/BRIK_ragdolls) means.

Wikipedia defines: "The [Ragdoll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragdoll) is a cat breed with blue eyes and a distinct colorpoint coat."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the article you linked to, [rag doll *physics*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragdoll_physics) refers to the ability of a character in a video game or simulation to be able to react to falling over or being hit in a more dynamic way.

Rather than having to create specific animations for falling you could let the character fall and determine how it moves based on how it's limbs collide with each other or the ground and how they drag each other (as long as a correct hierarchical skeleton is present) when a force is applied.

These are calculated on-the-fly in the game engine when the game is run rather than having been predefined beforehand (though they could have been limited to only have a certain amount of effect or be set to mix with a key framed animation).

The addon appears to help with the setting up of the collision boxes and game logic for the limbs that are necessary for accurate collisions.

The term rag doll is used because as the character or object falls it may have the appearance of a doll as it loses stiffness and collapses.

Answer (score 5):

Imagine you have a puppet with easily movable joints. If you throw it around, the puppet will move it's arms and legs according to the forces applied to it. Kind of like an unconscious person.

Here's a simple example I made to answer the question in a visual way. This is a ragdoll:

[image]

I have no idea why he is showing one last sign of life trying to sit up again. I didn't animate that in.

Wikipedia does have an article about the topic:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragdoll_physics